# Drupal Commerce and large product inventories

Tags: 8, commerce

Does anyone have any insight into using Drupal commerce with a large inventory? We are utilising using Drupal 8.1 headless and scoping an eCommerce integration using Drupal Commerce with around 30 million products. Currently, our thoughts are to use a MongoDB backend and Elasticsearch on top of it.

Does anyone have any experience or insight into handling such a large inventory and our planned approach?

The products will not have to be managed via the front end and instead will be imported with their various categories and attributes. Any changes we plan to do from a staging database and synchronise accordingly.

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 2):

The Akademika [case study](https://www.drupal.org/case-study/ecommerce-store-with-15-million-products) might help. They're at 18 million products right now, regular MySQL database plus Elasticsearch.

You can find the NyMedia team in #commerce on Drupal Slack (or contact them directly).

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Despite my web searching this is the only resource i've seen that discusses this.